# Function in a variable, passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameter-passing

I can't seem to get back on track with this one. I simply put a function in a variable and want to call it later, providing it with a parameter:

```
var logic = function(itemId) {               
    console.log(itemId);
};

jQuery("#flipright").click(function() {  logic.apply(1); } );
```

This prints "undefinded".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call `logic(1)`.
If you want to pass a context, you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

```
logic.apply(context, [1]);
// or
logic.call(context, 1);
```

You should use `apply` or `call` if you want to pass a context to another function - meaning that the `this` keyword in the called function will refer to whatever context you are passing to it.
Here's a scenario :

```
var logic = function(itemId) {               
    console.log(this,itemId);
};

jQuery("#flipright").click(function() {  
    // output to console the current jquery object and "1"
    logic.call(this,1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it:

```
jQuery("#flipright").click(function() {  logic(1); } );
```

ref for `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply